# Pan Gesture View slide up/ down animation is not smooth

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have implemented animation with pangesture and facing some issues as the animation doesn't look smooth and the position of view is not set to its actual starting position.

Take a look at the following image to understand the animation.

[image]

The following is my code to handle pan gesture and move my view according to animation.

```
@objc func wasDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    //return
    print(gestureRecognizer.state.rawValue)
    let direction = gestureRecognizer.direction(in: gestureRecognizer.view!)

    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {

        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        print(gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)

        if((gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y) < minY){

            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x, y:(minY - 1))
        }

        if(gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y < (self.pagingView.frame.size.height - 100) && gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y > (minY - 1)) {

            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)

        }else {

            if(direction == .Up){
                print("UP")
                if(gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y  > (minY - 1 )){
                    gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
                }else{
                    gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x, y:CGFloat(minY))
                }
            }else if(direction == .Down){
                print("Down")
                if((gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y - (minY-1)) > 100){
                    gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x, y:(self.pagingView.frame.size.height - 100))
                }else{
                    gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x, y:minY)
                }
            }
        }
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: self.view)
    }
}
```

The issue I am facing with the above code is that the view transition is not smooth. How to implement logic where if user left the finger from half of the screen then it should automatically set the view to initial portion?

Comment: Please re-format your code according to common rules: delete useless empty lines, fix spacing, and fix indentation.

Comment: You don't have any animation code, so what animation are you talking about?

Comment: @meaning-matters I am talking about the view animation that will be dragged down or up

Comment: @meaning-matters this is jus a testing code that I m doing trial & error anyways I have formatted it.

Comment: Formatting code is a good habit whatever you're working on. But then, when you present you code here and **ask for help** it's a matter of respect to present your question as clean & clear as possible.